# Grouping of Push Notifications using PushApps in android?

Tags: android, notifications, pushapps

I have implemented push notifications via PushApps.
My requirement is that, if user get multiple notifications then i need to show as a single notification with number of notifications counts.

```
PushManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setShouldStackNotifications(false);
```

Grouping is working fine with above line but number of notification count are not displaying.
Please suggest me something.
Thanks.